# how to disable codeigniter cache in specific function. if codeigniter is enable

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter cache is enable, but i want to disable the cache for my search controller. please help me that how to disable the codeigniter cache for any specific function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you reed the documentation, you can see that if you want to cache some view in method you need to put

```
class Somthing extends CI_Controller{
    function one(){//with cache
        $data['variabe'] = $this->model->get_somthing();
        $this->load->view('view', $data);

        $this->output->cache($seconds);
    }

    fucntion two(){//without cache
        $data['variabe'] = $this->model->get_somthing();
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class MY_Cacheoff extends CI_Cacheoff {
        /**
         * author: https://www.blazingcoders.com
         */
        function disable_cache() {
            $this->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            $this->set_header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
            $this->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
            $this->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
            $this->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
        }

    }
```

For more detail check the link

https://www.blazingcoders.com/how-to-disable-browser-cache-easily-for-particular-individual-and-separate-function-and-controller-in-codeigniter

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue